# Where should questions about ChatGPT troubleshooting be asked on Stack Exchange? I guess on Web Applications SE? And if not, where do they fit?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, chatgpt

I found 39 questions when searching for "ChatGPT" and the tag "chatgpt". This is a hint that Web Applications is the right Stack Exchange for ChatGPT. Yet, I wonder whether I have overseen something. Perhaps, there is some AI Stack Exchange that I oversaw? Or is there another Stack Exchange that fits?

I would like to know where a question like this is on-topic:

```
What can be done if ChatGPT is stuck?
```

My aim is to share that refreshing the site (F5) is all you need to get further - at least sometimes, as it worked for me once when I waited for many minutes and got the output rightaway after pressing F5.

*Mind that this meta question is not about where to put self-answered questions. I only show you this to make clearer what I am planning to do so that you can see what I mean with troubleshooting. I plan to share this small trick of F5, that is all. You might say that this is too easy to be shared, but strangely, I did not find this out for many hours even though I often press F5 in other web apps when I troubleshoot. I thought that ChatGPT lagged, but in the end, it was my browser, or it needed this trigger.*

Where should I put such a question? Should questions about ChatGPT troubleshooting be asked on Web Applications Stack Exchange? And if not, where do they fit (bonus question since it might be that this question is off-topic on any Stack Exchange).

#### Long story on a returned question with a rejected migration

I still do not know why I kept the question on MSE with its points, but I know that the two, here and there, are treated on their own. Perhaps someone can tell me what is going on here.

##### Migration to MSE was rejected, question was returned

This question was migrated to Meta Stack Exchange, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395924/787861), then it was returned here, so that the migration to MSE was rejected:

[image]

In the timeline, this rejected migration means that it was rejected on the side of MSE, so that this question was returned to Meta Web Applications SE:

[image]

Yet, there is now the strange thing that the MSE question is still listed on MSE so that I still seem to have the malus points there even if it was returned here. I guess that this happens if votes and edits and answers happen on MSE and the question gets returned afterwards only as the old, unedited question, without points of course, but also without the MSE answer of another user who is also on Web Applications SE.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The question on MSE is then treated as if it was a new question. I therefore copied and pasted the whole question from MSE back to Meta Web Applications SE, the questions were and are not aligned, I only made them the same with my copies (!).

##### Unfair downvotes = malus points on MSE

Now it seems that I have to cope with the many downvotes on Meta Stack Exchange (10 downvotes, 2 upvotes) even though I did not ask to migrate it there. Since I am banned on MSE, such downvotes prolong the time of being banned again. I asked a meta question about this problem on Meta Stack Overflow (as a placeholder to be migrated to MSE since I am banned there): [Web Applications meta question was migrated to Meta Stack Exchange and back, but which was rejected. Now I have 10 unneeded downvotes more on MSE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427700/11154841). Yet, firstly, Stack Overflow was unwilling to migrate it to MSE, saying that I would act against the rules. Secondly, it was deleted since I was told that the MSE question was returned many hours ago to Meta Web Applications SE, this could be seen in the timeline. Yet, at the same time when this can be seen in the timeline, I only see it being rejected. This turns out to be a misunderstanding on my side: the migration was rejected by MSE = returned to Web Applications SE, while I mistakenly thought that the return was rejected by Web Applications SE. Now in short, the deleted question on Meta Stack Overflow is understandable since I was wrong to say that the mirgration back was rejected. Yet, it is still unclear to me why the malus points together with the now deleted question on MSE count: I have not migrated the Meta Web Applications SE question there, and it was later returned and not deleted on Meta Web Applications SE, but I still have to bear the malus points. I see this as something that should be changed, it is like a feature request: I would like to get rid of the malus points on MSE if I did not migrate the question there and if the question later was returned. Since the malus point system is automated, such malus points count as if it was my fault. Since I am banned on MSE, there is no SE for me to ask for such a feature request. I ask for a new feature that allows banned members to ask questions even if they are banned if they tag it with `ban` so that such things can be discussed in the right channel (not here, not on Meta Stack Overflow).

Comment: Depending on the question, maybe try [GenAI Stack Exchange](https://genai.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones That seems to be only about getting work done together with the bot. There seems to be no merely end-user technical tag. I guess that such a technical example question as above is just about ChatGPT as a web application, not about it as someone to talk to in the right way, and it is not even clear whether the lag that the example question is about is a problem of ChatGPT as such, it could also be a memory or protocol problem of the browser.

Comment: I found [How is the "Corresponding requests per minute (RPM)" calculated when creating a GPT deployment in Azure?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/402/3022) with the tags `gpt` and `openai`. The question might be a hint why the bot lags sometimes: it needs more than one token for the query, and sometimes, it does not get it and stops asking for it unless you refresh the browser. This example question above might survive there. I think your remark is worth an answer, together with that link that I found. I will ask to migrated it there if the question gets downvoted and closed again.

Comment: You might try flagging your original MSE question, asking a moderator whether anything can be done to reduce the question ban time in MSE, as you did not ask to migrate the question there. But I don't expect much to happen.

Comment: @TheMaster from the faq that every question banned user gets: "Moderators cannot lift the ban". https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/369802. Perhaps don't suggest users take steps that won't carry any result because the system doesn't allow for any results.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I do not ask to lift the ban, I ask to take away the new malus points since they prolong my ban time. This is something new, like a feature request that could be passed further to the community since I do not think that moderators have the power to clear those malus points (deleted question and the 10 downvotes), and I do not have any other channel than to flag this here to reach a moderator since I am banned on MSE.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell This is due to special circumstances like migration. I was a bit confused by OP's statement: "Since I am banned on MSE, such downvotes prolong the time of being banned again". It seems OP was already banned. So, a migration should've been blocked. But that didn't happen. Nevertheless, I didn't ask to lift the ban, but to reduce the question ban time, maybe by *post dissociation*, as OP didn't intend to ask there at all. **I don't see why OP should be extended punishment for something completely out of his control**.

Comment: @questionto42 Post dissociation seems to reduce post block time: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225997/ I've seen moderators do it. But, since you're banned, you can simply https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact > StackExchange Q/A issue > My question or answer was denied > Message: Request Post disassociation. Post link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395924/ Reason: I never asked the question to be migrated to MSE and therefore shouldn't be responsible for the votes there. I shouldn't be punished for something out of my control Detail Post: https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212/

Comment: FYI, I should note that question migrations are supposed to be disabled (blocked automatically if attempted) if the author is banned from posting questions on the destination site. The fact that it was allowed in this case appears to be a design fault.

Comment: Also, as far as a copy of the question still existing on Meta.SE: rejected migrations on the destination site are deleted after a 30-day waiting period by an automated script. The waiting period is so users on the destination site can know what happened and why.

Comment: Relevant global meta discussion post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396263/should-migrations-continue-to-be-allowed-if-the-author-is-question-banned-but-th

Comment: Related: 1. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396260/votes-on-rejected-migration-on-destination-site-should-not-contribute-positively 2. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396263/should-migrations-continue-to-be-allowed-if-the-author-is-question-banned-but-th

Comment: @TheMaster Moderators also *can not* dissociate posts. That is why the faq guidance on question blocks says that *moderators cannot lift the ban*. We can not do anything so telling users to 'try flagging [...] asking a moderator' *is* useless advice that will only frustrate other users. As for "I don't expect much to happen", you were right. Nothing *can* happen, so that's a very self-fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell A few years back, I flagged one of my posts for dissociation and it happened. If moderators can't do it, perhaps they escalated it to community managers?  Nevertheless, something did happen: You commented, I researched and provided a probable way for OP. In an ideal world, this should've been recommended by the moderators themselves instead of a third party such as me - If you can't do any action, you can still provide advice and you knew about disassociation and that this would be very valid case for it -  advising users as such is well within moderators' purview.

Comment: @TheMaster hence me leaving my first comment here: Advising users is well within my purview, so whenever I see a flag linking to a comment with blatantly wrong information, I *do* go and leave a comment myself to say the information is wrong, in the hope future users are advised not to do the wrong thing again.

Comment: I have also linked the appropriate resources for the user to read in both my first comment and the comment on the wrong flag, in this case the faq on post bans, which also includes guidance on the right step to take when the user really feels the ban is in error. There was no need for you to provide anything, as it was already provided.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell To quote, [Mad scientist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225990), *In practice this is not really an issue as far as I know. The kind of user that hits the question ban is unlikely to know about this rather obscure feature.*. It is intentionally not written in your FAQ, which just says *If you really, really think the ban is an error, then email the team directly using the "contact us" link provided at the bottom of every page*. **But note that reactivation of banned accounts is not a high priority.**.

Comment: Mine is a legal right and should happen. Yours is a solution, a last line in an essay, which may or may not happen.  Offering generalised advise to a specific question, without looking into it's specifics is a disappointing work for a moderator.

Comment: @TheMaster I made a post dissociation request, see the changes in the answer. This may well be workaround enough to end the discussion if it is so rare a thing what happened here.

Comment: @TheMaster moderators simply cannot affect question bans in any way. We cannot impose them, lift them, make them longer or shorter. Only employees can do that, if it is even possible. This has nothing to do with the specifics of this question, it is just how the mechanics of the site work. So yes, suggesting a mod can reduce a q-ban is blatantly wrong information. Same with dissociation requests. Mods cannot do that. We used to, more than ten years ago, but not now and not for the last decade at least. Only employees can do that.

Comment: @terdon The advise isn't asking moderators to reduce/remove question ban. My exact quote is **asking a moderator whether anything can be done to reduce the question ban time in MSE, as you did not ask to migrate the question there.** Moderators are exception handlers and know ins and outs of these exceptions and so they may have a more direct advise for your situation instead of generalised advise.This is a very specific situation/ exception,which moderators could've surely helped by providing great advise.

Comment: @terdon To repeat, Mods don't have to actually do anything. Their knowledge itself is highly valuable.  This isn't exactly about question ban either. I would argue it is actually a dissociation request in disguise, without mentioning the word  "dissoaciation", as OP didn't know about it. Repeatedly, OP is asking for that migration and the votes on this question to not be his - just in different words.

Comment: @TheMaster Without the user *explicitly* asking for disassociation (or the equivalent of "please remove attribution to me from [this content]"), moderators and SE can't do anything. It's a legal thing. Asking mods "whether anything can be done" is, effectively, useless, as flags are not *able* to have discussions (mods can make a single, *very* short response to *post* flags and *no response* to comment flags). The CC BY-SA license permits attribution to be removed **only** at the request of the author. So, yes, your specific advice above is bad/wrong/*useless*.

Comment: @TheMaster If the author of the post raises a flag explicitly asking for disassociation, *then* a moderator can forward the request to CMs. However, that's inefficient. It expends the moderator's time to relay the request and delays the response to the user's request. The way that such a request should be made is for the user to use the "[Contact/Contact Us](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/contact)" link that's at the bottom of every page. That's as explained in: "[How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/271271)"

Comment: @Makyen That is what I did now after a remark above from TheMaster (search for "StackExchange Q/A issue" to find it). Works.

Comment: Yeah, @TheMaster, that's my point: in this case, mods can do NO THING more than regular users so please don't suggest that users should "*try flagging your original MSE question, asking a moderator whether anything can be done*" because that is a waste of the users' and the mods' time. Instead, the users should use the "contact us" link, as the OP here actually did. That's all, just don't put mods in the loop since that will just add an extra step for no benefit.

Comment: @Makyen I really don't see "whether anything can be done" is, effectively, useless. Couldn't you have recommended dissociation in the flag reply, based on this post, if linked on the flag, for example?

Comment: @terdon *mods can do NO THING more than regular user* **What about knowledge?**  I expect mods to know more than regular users and therefore, if they're willing to help, they know to. If the user isn't on any other SE site, you guys are probably their only hope. They probably don't even know about the contact form.

Comment: When I mean kind mods, I meant mods who would go the extra mile, even for banned users - try to be extra helpful  and have hope against odds- that this user might become a productive member later on. In this case - due to specifics of this case, recommend dissociation in contact form in the flag reply or even just the contact form or even escalate to CMs, due to the specific circumstances of this case- That's what I expect a super positive helpful mod to do. I agree it is extremely rare to find such a mod and much more rare for the flag to find such a mod.

Comment: @TheMaster You're literally suggesting "tell users to ask moderators if there's anything that can be done and have the mods tell them what I could have told them to do in the first place". *That's useless*. Just tell them the right thing up front. Don't waste their time and moderator time putting an additional layer of redirection on the issue.

Comment: @Makyen That's assuming I knew post disassociation would be helpful in post bans. I didn't at that time. But I assume a mod would have known. So, if you knew, Couldn't you have recommended dissociation in the flag reply, based on this post, if linked on the flag, for example? Wouldn't that have helped?

Comment: I still don't know a lot of things you guys do. It was pure luck, that I even thought of dissociation and then researched(Which I wouldn't have done, if it weren't for a Mod comment). But it was also because of OP's persistence. Anyone who put in this much effort deserves a second chance, even if they're destined to fail.

Comment: @TheMaster as I am trying to explain, in the specific case of question bans, mods can't do anything at all. Nothing. So flagging is a waste of everyone's time. So instead of telling people to flag, tell them to use the contact form. You suggested that asking mods is the right thing to do. We are explaining that no, using the contact form is the right thing to do. We have now said it, so there is nothing more to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### As for the right Stack Exchange

I have now just tried it, the question was closed on Super User saying "Web applications and services are off topic here." That is why I will ask to migrate it to Web Applications SE now. That is why I guess that it will fit only here, if at all, and that therefore the meta question was asked here on the right Stack Exchange.

In the meantime, the question was migrated from Super User SE to Web Applications SE at [What can be done if ChatGPT 3.5 is stuck for minutes while working on an answer?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/173439/253420) and seems to survive with the editing of some helping hands.

##### As for the unfair malus points on MSE

As the remark above shows, I can ask for a so-called dissociation:

> Post dissociation seems to reduce post block time:
> meta.stackexchange.com/a/225997 I've seen moderators do it. But, since
> you're banned, you can simply meta.stackexchange.com/contact >
> StackExchange Q/A issue > My question or answer was denied > Message:
> Request Post disassociation. Post link:
> meta.stackexchange.com/q/395924 Reason: I never asked the question to
> be migrated to MSE and therefore shouldn't be responsible for the
> votes there. I shouldn't be punished for something out of my control
> Detail Post: webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212 –  TheMaster

Thus, here is this in screenshots:

[image]

[image]

This is now also on MSE at [Votes on rejected migration on destination site should not contribute positively or negatively to post ban calculation on the destination site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/396272/787861).

After only an hour or two, I got a mail that

> the post has been disassociated from your account as requested.

By this, the malus points have been cleared, as if the question was never migrated to MSE (and then rejected to be returned to Web Apps SE).

Comment: Thanks for investing all the time in this as well as the actual question. It isn't always clear what to do in a particular situation and  your approach is commendable. Thank you for your contributions!

Comment: @Blindspots No meta noise needed! :) All good, business as usual. May the risk be with us.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what everything except the smiley emoji and "business as usual" meant in that comment. :-)  Be well!